# German umlauts in powershell. Iterate over directory does not work

Tags: powershell

I am trying to iterate over a folder. It works for all folder but not for directories with umauts in it.
Following script shows what the problem is:

```
$source= @("D:\XLS_Abrufe-ÜNB")
foreach ($element in $source) {
    $element
    cmd /c dir /ad /b /s $element |foreach{
        $_
    }
}
```

Output:

```
D:\XLS_Abrufe-ÜNB

D:\XLS_Abrufe-šNB\2015
D:\XLS_Abrufe-šNB\2016
D:\XLS_Abrufe-šNB\2017
```

If i try to work on with these names, it won't find the folders.
Any ideas how to get this with work with umlauts?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get all of the directories within `D:\XLS_Abrufe-ÜNB`?  From my experience, cmd does not handle unicode very well.

```
$source= @("D:\XLS_Abrufe-ÜNB")
Get-ChildItem $source -force |
  Where-Object { $_.IsPSContainer } |
  $_
```

Comment: Yes, i try to get all subdirectories recursive. In the complete program i then sort and zip speicific folders. I don't know how to get your code works for me, but i think i tried such an aproach in the beginning, but was too slow, or failed because these folders contain millions of files.

Comment: Ok. I now use following. It is ten times slower than the dir command (2 sec vs 20 sec just for iterating without payload), but that is fast enough.     

Get-ChildItem -recurse $element -force -attributes Directory | foreach {    
    $_.FullName
}

Answer (score 1):

You are shelling out an external command, in this case the `cmd` prompt, which uses the console host. In Windows, the console host still uses code pages, so while PowerShell understands the character just fine, the console host is likely not understanding the encoding.

If you use native PowerShell all the way ([as in TheIncorrigible1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702511/3905079)) it should work just fine.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 for such a small edit I would just notify the poster. It should be fixed but leave to the op or users with more rep for <6 character edits.

Comment: @Matt I get notified of the edit anyway; and I did the "improve edit" so that I could make it live right away instead of waiting for it to get trough the queue.

Comment: I understand that but superfluous changes to make the character limit is not really advisable

Comment: @Matt I agree; it would have been better to just notify me and avoid the queue altogether.

Comment: I'm newer to SO and am unfamiliar.  I'll direct-notify in the future.